# What Package is '/usr/sbin/apache2' part of?

Tags: apt, package-management, apache2

After I installed Apache trough the command sequence you can find below, it gave me an error: `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 171: /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: /usr/sbin/apache2: not found`. After some Googling I found out that it's part of a dependency of Apache2, which apparently is missing. Does anyone know which dependency that is?

Command Sequence:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2.2-common
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apache2ctl start -k
```

---

After some more Googling I figured I should try `sudo service apache2 start` which gives me the error: `No apache MPM package installed`. I tried to install that package by using the command `sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork`. I posted the results of that here.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apache2-mpm-worker
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2-mpm-prefork
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2.398 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: apache2-mpm-worker: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 apache2 depends on apache2-mpm-worker (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) | apache2-mpm-prefork (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) | apache2-mpm-event (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) | apache2-mpm-itk (= 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4); however:
  Package apache2-mpm-worker is to be removed.
  Package apache2-mpm-prefork is not installed.
  Package apache2-mpm-event is not installed.
  Package apache2-mpm-itk is not installed.
(Reading database ... 267257 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing apache2-mpm-worker ...
No apache MPM package installed
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-mpm-prefork.
(Reading database ... 267251 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking apache2-mpm-prefork (from .../apache2-mpm-prefork_2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up apache2-mpm-prefork (2.2.22-1ubuntu1.4) ...
No apache MPM package installed
```

Comment: What happens if you try: `sudo apt-get remove apache2-mpm-worker` and `sudo apt-get install apache2-mpm-prefork` separately?

Comment: @Jos It removes and reinstalls, with console messages very similar to the one mentioned in the OP. (`No apache MPM package installed`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue by removing all packages stating with 'apache', and than installing Apache again.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --purge gezgsdgdfg*
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dpkg command to figure out the package the files belongs to

`dpkg -S /path/to/file`

For example:

```sh
$ dpkg -S /usr/sbin/apache2ctl
apache2.2-common: /usr/sbin/apache2ctl
```

This file belongs to package `apache2.2-common`.

Comment: So Google was wrong and it wasn't a missing package? `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/sbin/apache2`

Comment: Forgot to mention I tested on Ubuntu 12.04.3.

Comment: I'm also running 12.04. That can't be what's wrong.